# Can the cube root of this matrix be found?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations, random-matrices

I tried to find the matrix X which satisfies X$^3$=$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ by using the method of diagonalization only to realise that it doesn't work for this type of matrix (which has an eigenvalue of $1$). Furthermore, I tried to use induction to show that $X^n$=$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-n & 1\end{bmatrix}$ because i figured i could just set $n=1$. I would be very grateful if someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are already aware that $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -3 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ which is straightforward to check. On the other hand this problem has more than a solution, so "* **the** matrix $X$ which satisfies*" is improper.

Comment: Though it does appear that the matrix you've found is the only real matrix solution (there are two more complex ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X = \pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d\cr}$, you want 
$$ \eqalign{ \left( {a}^{2}+bc \right) b+ \left( ab+bd \right) d&=0\cr
 \left( {a}^{2}+bc \right) a+ \left( ab+bd \right) c-1&=0\cr
 \left( ac+cd \right) a+ \left( bc+{d}^{2} \right) c+3&=0\cr
 \left( ac+cd \right) b+ \left( bc+{d}^{2} \right) d-1&=0\cr}$$
which can be solved algebraically, yielding
$$ \eqalign{a &= d\cr b &= 0\cr c &= -d\cr d^3 &= 1\cr} $$
So the only real solution is indeed
$$ \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr -1 & 1\cr} $$

EDIT: You may prefer this slightly more general solution.  You want to solve 
the $2\times 2$ matrix equation $X^3 = I+N$ where $N \ne 0$, $N^2 = 0$ and $X$ is real.
The eigenvalues of $X$ must all be cube roots of $1$ (the eigenvalues of $X^3$ are the cubes of the eigenvalues of $X$, by the Spectral Mapping Theorem).  If the real matrix $X$ has a non-real eigenvalue, it has the complex conjugate eigenvalue as well, and then $X$ would have two distinct eigenvalues, therefore be diagonalizable, which is impossible since $I+N$ is not diagonalizable.  So the only eigenvalue of $X$ is $1$ (a repeated eigenvalue).  Thus $X = I + M$ where $M$ is nilpotent; since these are $2 \times 2$ matrix that means $M^2 = 0$.  But then by the binomial theorem, 
$X^3 = (I+M)^3 = I + 3 M$, so $M=N/3$.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, consider the equation $X^3=I_n+N$ where the unknown is $X\in M_n$ and $N\in M_n$ is a nilpotent known matrix.

Then a particular solution is given by the binomial formula

$X=(I+N)^{1/3}=I+1/3N-1/9N^2+\cdots$. Note that the previous sum is finite !